# how to make a real empty string with VLOOKUP in MS EXCEL?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using `vlookup` in MS Excel to replace a blank cell with a empty string like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(A2;[book.xlsx]sheet1!$C$1:$F$521;4;FALSE))=0;""; VLOOKUP(A2;[book.xlsx]sheet1$C$1:$F$521;4;FALSE));"")
```

Now, I am trying to a `OR` condition for two cells obtained by the vlookup, say `=OR(J51>=9.5; N51>=9.5)` and if one of the cells was replaced by "" (with the vlookup function) the `OR` condition becames TRUE even if there is no data in the cells.

I have no ideia why... can someone give an explanation for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any *text* (even a blank string) is greater than any number in Excel. Try using `N()` like this: `=OR(N(J51)>=9.5; N(N51)>=9.5)`

Comment: @Rory Thank you!... pretty simple...Didnot know that!